# How to trigger a script with udev when connecting sda, but NOT sda1-x

Tags: linux, udev

I need to run a script, when connecting a usb-drive to an embedded system.
My idea was:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add", KERNELS=="sd?",RUN+="/script param1 %k"
```

It needs to run with any usb-stick, so I am not able to use Vendor-specific parameters. Now the script executes with sd[a..][*,1..], but it should only execute when sd[a..]*
 connects (_ for NULL).
With the ? it works when disconnecting, but on connecting, it executes for each partition
Is there any possibility or do I habe to parse this in the Shell-Script?

Would be nice, if anyone could help me here. (If someone saw, that I deleted the Question: sorry, I thought, the ? was the final solution. But it didn work either).

Here is the output of udevadm info --attribute-walk -name /dev/sda1

```
  looking at device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1':
    KERNEL=="sda1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{partition}=="1"
    ATTR{start}=="63"
    ATTR{size}=="1526112"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="4294935040"
    ATTR{stat}=="       0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/fsl-ehci.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda':
    KERNELS=="sda"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="block"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{range}=="16"
    ATTRS{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTRS{removable}=="1"
    ATTRS{ro}=="0"
    ATTRS{size}=="15656960"
    ATTRS{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTRS{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTRS{capability}=="51"
    ATTRS{stat}=="       1        0        8        4        0        0        0        0        0        4        4"
    ATTRS{inflight}=="       0        0"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just having the script exit when it's called with `/dev/sd??*` ?

Comment: I do so now, yes.. but its not realy elegant in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add", KERNELS=="sd*[!0-9]", RUN+="/script param1 %k"
```

`sd*` will match any characters, but `[!0-9]` will exclude the partition numbers, so you're left with block devices only.

At least on a CentOS 6 systems there are a lot of rules in /lib/udev/rules.d. The rule file 60-persistent-storage.rules defines rules like the one above.